# How to do Poisson Generalized mixed models with autoregressive covariance structure

Tags: r, mixed-models, autoregressive-models

I'm looking into R libraries that can fit an autoregressive poisson mixed model. The only one I seem to find is glmmPQL, which is giving me errors. Here's my code:

```
MASS::glmmPQL(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3, random= ~ 1 | USER_ID/DATE, data=xy, family=poisson, 
              correlation=corAR1(), verbose=FALSE)
```

This throws the following error:

```
Error in corAR() : could not find function "corAR"
```

When I remove the 'correlation' parameter to check if glmmPQL runs otherwise, it runs, but the output shows AIC and BIC are `NA`

Any suggestions on how to fix this or if there are other libraries for fitting this model?

Comment: Is `library(nlme)` loaded?

Comment: @jay.sf that was it! that solved the problem of the corAR() error, but I am still getting NA for AIC and BIC, any idea why? (feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it)